# arcpy create composite address locator

Tags: arcpy, geocoding, address

I am making a script for creating address locators and then composite address locator. As I was reading the arcpy help documents I found the syntax here http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/geocoding/create-composite-address-locator.htm. For the **in_field_map** parameter, the example gives a long string with few explanation on the syntax. Where can I find more details on how to format this parameter?

Comment: [Mapping input fields to output fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/mapping-fields.htm) is a good starting place to understanding field mapping.

Answer (score 1):

After researching for a little while, I found it's possible to view the script syntax after running the tool in ArcMap/ArcCatalog. In result window, right-click to copy as python snippet and view the script with my own data path in the parameter. It will be easier to understand the syntax with your own data.